# How can I switch in C++ code the ARMEABI-V7A assembler to ARM64?

Tags: android, c++, assembly, arm64

I have an old code written for armeabi-v7a and I need to switch it to arm64-v8a. The part of the code is written as macro in assembler and the instruction set is not supported for arm64-v8a how it was supported for armeabi-v7a.

```
    #define LOAD_ARGS_0()
    #define ASM_ARGS_0
    #define LOAD_ARGS_1(a1)             \
      int _a1tmp = (int) (a1);          \
      LOAD_ARGS_0 ()                \
      _a1 = _a1tmp;
    #define ASM_ARGS_1  ASM_ARGS_0, "r" (_a1)
    #define LOAD_ARGS_2(a1, a2)         \
      int _a2tmp = (int) (a2);          \
      LOAD_ARGS_1 (a1)              \
      register int _a2 asm ("a2") = _a2tmp;
    #define ASM_ARGS_2  ASM_ARGS_1, "r" (_a2)
    #define LOAD_ARGS_3(a1, a2, a3)         \
      int _a3tmp = (int) (a3);          \
      LOAD_ARGS_2 (a1, a2)              \
      register int _a3 asm ("a3") = _a3tmp;
    #define ASM_ARGS_3  ASM_ARGS_2, "r" (_a3)
    #define LOAD_ARGS_4(a1, a2, a3, a4)     \
      int _a4tmp = (int) (a4);          \
      LOAD_ARGS_3 (a1, a2, a3)          \
      register int _a4 asm ("a4") = _a4tmp;
    #define ASM_ARGS_4  ASM_ARGS_3, "r" (_a4)
    #define LOAD_ARGS_5(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)     \
      int _v1tmp = (int) (a5);          \
      LOAD_ARGS_4 (a1, a2, a3, a4)          \
      register int _v1 asm ("v1") = _v1tmp;
    #define ASM_ARGS_5  ASM_ARGS_4, "r" (_v1)
    #define LOAD_ARGS_6(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6) \
      int _v2tmp = (int) (a6);          \
      LOAD_ARGS_5 (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)      \
      register int _v2 asm ("v2") = _v2tmp;
    #define ASM_ARGS_6  ASM_ARGS_5, "r" (_v2)
    # define LOAD_ARGS_7(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7)    \
      int _v3tmp = (int) (a7);              \
      LOAD_ARGS_6 (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6)          \
      register int _v3 asm ("v3") = _v3tmp;
    # define ASM_ARGS_7 ASM_ARGS_6, "r" (_v3)
    # define INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW(name, err, nr, args...)       \
      ({                                \
           register int _a1 asm ("r0"), _nr asm ("r7");     \
           LOAD_ARGS_##nr (args)                    \
           _nr = name;                      \
           __asm__ __volatile__ ("swi   0x0 @ syscall " #name   \
                 : "=r" (_a1)               \
                 : "r" (_nr) ASM_ARGS_##nr          \
                 : "memory");               \
           _a1; })
```

The compiler reports - 
error: unknown register name 'a2' in asm 
res = INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW (__NR_set_robust_list, NULL, 2, &pd->robust_head, sizeof (f_robust_list_head_type));

This macro is called as -

```
res = INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW (__NR_set_robust_list, NULL, 2, &pd->robust_head, sizeof (f_robust_list_head_type));
```

Can somebody of you help me with that?

Comment: Get a recent version of MUSL libc or something and use their syscall macro for AArch64.  The calling convention is different and registers are 64-bit so if you don't already know asm well enough to port this yourself, just get an AArch64 version of the macro.

Comment: Try using the `syscall` function instead.

Comment: Thank a lot. I was doing it based on MUSL libc for AArch64, it is can be compiled, but it doesn't work. In logcat it shows an error in the place of this calling.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your hints. I've tried to do it based on MUSL libc and also using by calling `syscall` directly, but I've always got the following error in logcat: `seccomp prevented call to disallowed arm64 system call 0`